# Run setupclass as admin and remaining test as a standard user

Tags: python, windows, testing

I am trying to run a test which sets some of the Windows registry keys, for which I need to run the test as an admin. I want to test the remaining parts as a standard user. This is for an automated test, so I can't create two scripts and run one in admin mode and the other in standard mode.

```
class abctest(unittest.Testcase):

    def setUpClass(cls):
        set_regkeys

   def setup(self):
       Normaluser_setup

   def test1(self):
       do teststeps
```

Comment: sorry about the code format , I didnt get how to format it properly

Comment: It's possible to remove groups and privileges from your access token, but you can't get them back after they're removed. It may be simpler to "runas" `ShellExecute` the current script as an elevated process.